# How to reconnect to disconnected slurm compute node?

Tags: slurm

I started a compute node using srun on a SLURM cluster. My SSH connection got severed but my node is still active and consuming GPU resources. How do i reconnect to this node?

Answer (score 1):

`srun` doesn't start a node in Slurm. It starts an interactive job with a shell session on an existing node. The node is active and other jobs are consuming resources on the node. A job dies when the user disconnects from the node unless a utility like `tmux` or `screen` is used.

Comment: However from my end using "sinfo" and squeue I can see that my node/job is still active despite me disconnecting. How do I reconnect?

Comment: @JobHunter69 `sinfo` simply shows that the node is active which is was prior to your job running. It doesn't affect whether a node is up or down. Submitting a job just sends it to the scheduler so that it can be assigned to a node which is what you did with `srun`. `sinfo` also doesn't provide information on jobs. It just lists and shows the state of the nodes themselves. The commands that give the status of jobs are `squeue` for jobs that are running and `sacct` for jobs that have completed. All of this information is available in the `man` pages and via Google.

Comment: @JobHunter69 If you still have a job running on that node, then the only way that it's the interactive job that you submitted is if there was a screen session. If not, the job would stop when the shell session is disconnecting. Otherwise, there is a different, non-interactive job running on the same node. Your job does not activate a node. It will continue be active whether you or anyone has a job on it or not unless it goes down via a malfunction or it's taken down with the cluster manager.

Comment: What do you mean by screen session? I don't really understand why the job is still running after i lose connection

Comment: @JobHunter69 If your SSH session was truly ended, then your interactive job is no longer running on the node. That would have killed all of the processes that were started during that session regardless of how they were started. If you don't know what screen is, then you weren't using it. If you have a job running on it, then it's not your interactive job that was using SSH. If you need more information, consult with the person who manages the cluster.